# Issue with page numbering for mwrep document

Tags: header-footer, numbering, report

I have document `\documentclass[a4paper,onecolumn,twoside,12pt]{mwrep}` and I want to have custom style of page number for each page. To achieve this I've done this

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{custompagenum}{
    \fancyhf{} 
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} 
    \fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage} 
}
\pagestyle{custompagenum}
```

I achieved what I wanted when it comes to style but the page number is not appearing on the first page and the pages that are not fully covered. I found that if I change document class it works correctly but in such case all styles for sections are broken.

How can I fix it?